# Как не печатать картинку в HTML?

Tags: html, css

На странице с текстом есть, скажем, картинка с тэгом `img`, заключена в блок `div`:

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:16mm; top:8.6mm;">
    <img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/crystalclear/128x128/button_ok.png" />
</div>
```

**Как НЕ выводить её при печати, но чтобы отображалась при просмотре** в IE 6-8

Comment: Попробуй сделать условные комментарии для IE6-8.

Comment: Всё, спасибо, забыл немного: 
@media print{.unprintable{display:none;}}

div class="unprintable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
@media screen {
 div {
   display: block; / Отображаем элемент /
 }
}
@media print {
 div {
   display: none; / Прячем содержимое /
 }
}
```

А стили можно подгружать в зависимости от браузера
http://www.snippy.ru/snippet/85/

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоватся тем, что браузеры позволяют подгружать различные css в зависимости от режима отображения (а печать - это один с режимов)
Почитать можно [к примеру здесь](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). Но вот только я не знаю, поддерживает ли  6 IE все это.